# CSS style won't apply to Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, server, styles

I worked on localhost (Wordpress site) on child theme, added style.css in child theme and styles were applied and everything was ok.

When I pushed my (first) site online, style.css won't apply and my whole site isn't styled.

Also, when I inspect it, I can see added 'container' classes to every row. Is that some wordpress thing?

Does someone know, what is the problem? I am not getting any errors.

Thanks,
Marija.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't automatically add classes to your code, so its not a "Wordpress thing" - something else has done this. How did you move your site online? If you used a tool or plugin, it might have somehow made changes (although its an unusual thing for them to do). But I'm afraid there's not much else we can help with - it's not standard behaviour or a common issue so we don't really have anything to go on to help.

Comment: Are you sure it's even set to use your theme? There is no reason for WordPress too add extra container classes unless it's via a theme or plugin.

Comment: It was silly problem. I forgot to add theme plugin  when I published page. Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache form your website. Then try again, Check you active your working theme or not

Comment: Thank you, but that isn't solution for my problem.